# Como almacenar un color de un JButton en una BD SQLite

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Mi programa puede crear JButtons dinamicamente, Se le agrega el Text y el valor que me regresaran al dar Click:

```
String name = nameField.getText();
    String identification = idField.getText();
    Person person = new Person(name, identification);
    insertarVendedores(name, identification);

    JButton personButton = new JButton(new PersonAction(person));
    pnlVen.add(personButton);
    pnlVen.revalidate();
    pnlVen.repaint();
    nameField.setText("");
    idField.setText("");
    CargarTablaVendedores("");
```

Despues, Los carga desde una base de datos SQLite:

```
try{
        Connection miConexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:vendedores2Claro.db");
    Statement miStatement = miConexion.createStatement();
    ResultSet miResultSet = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT id, name, identification FROM vendedores2Claro");

    while(miResultSet.next()){
            pnlVen.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification")))));
            pnlVen.revalidate();
            pnlVen.repaint();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Pero los botones se vuelven indistinguibles al ser todos de un color, Y pues necesito ayuda en que me digan como puedo hacer para que en el momento de llenar el formulario para que el usuario cree el JButton seleccione desde un combo Box el color de ese nuevo JButton y que al cargarlo también cargue con ese color. Mil disculpas si doy demasiadas vueltas en mi pregunta, Y les agradezco por su atencion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola te arme este sencillo programa que genera botones y les asigna el color en base a un comboBox, espero te de una idea para implementar la solucion.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Window window = new Window();
        window.start();

    }
}


class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


    final String[] COLORS = {"Azul", "Rojo", "Verde"};

    private JButton generateButton = new JButton("Generar botones");
    private JComboBox colorBox = new JComboBox(COLORS);
    private List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();


    public Window() {

        setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        generateButton.addActionListener(this);
        add(generateButton);
        add(colorBox);
    }

    public void start() {
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {


        //Create a new button with the selected color
        JButton newButton = new JButton("Button" + (buttons.size() + 1));
        newButton.setBackground(getColor(colorBox.getSelectedItem() + ""));
        buttons.add(newButton);
        add(newButton);

        //Update change on the JFrame
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    private Color getColor(final String stringColor) {
        switch (stringColor) {
            case "Azul":
                return Color.blue;
            case "Rojo":
                return Color.red;
            case "Verde":
                return Color.green;
            default:
                return Color.blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu codigo es oro para mis ojos, Pero ahora tengo un nuevo problema y es que no se me ocurre como hacer que al momento de cargar mis JButtons de la BD, se me aplique el color

Comment: pnlVen.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification")))));

Comment: el problema es que no se en que espacio de este codigo puedo agregar que si en la BD dice "Azul" entonces que se aplique

Comment: El color, en formato sRGB, no dejan de ser un entero. Porque simplemente no lo guarda en tu base de datos y luego creas el color con new Color(numero1). A la hora de presentarselo a los usuarios, muestrale una serie de colores ya predefinidos (una lista), no creo que sea buena idea que el usuario pueda introducir un texto arbitrario ;-)

Comment: Gracias por mostrarme otra forma de hacerlo, Lo aprecio, Pero mi problemilla esta en que cada vez que se inicia el programa, Los botones se crean de nuevo pero basandose en lo que se almaceno en la BD y pues mi problema esta en que no se de que manera puedo aplicarle el color, asi sea en formato sRGB, con el codigo que puse arribita de tu cometario es que se me crea recorriendose en un while, pero no se de que manera referirme y asignarle ese color, Soy principiante asi que hasta lo basico me sirve.

Comment: Pero en la base de datos tendrás X números de colores ya predefinidos, ¿ no ?.  Si es el caso, es guardar en esa tabla o en otra la relacion entre esos colores y su código sRGB.

Comment: Si osea, es que yo se como guardaria el color en la Bd, En eso no tengo problema, Lo que digo es que como hago para escribir el setBackground  in esta linea de código: pnlVen.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification")))));

Comment: Algo asi: add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification"))),setBackground(Color.yellow)));